# different output for FileReader and FileInputStream

Tags: java, filereader, fileinputstream

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader("C:\\test\\input.txt");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\input.txt");
        FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader("C:\\test\\abc.png");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\abc.png");

        int ab=fileReader1.read(); 
        int bc=fileInputStream1.read();

        int ab1=fileReader2.read();
        int bc1=fileInputStream2.read();

        System.out.println("reading a file : fileReader:"+ab+" fileInputStream:"+bc);
        System.out.println("resding  PNG : fileReader:"+ab1+" fileInputStream:"+bc1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
reading a file : fileReader:104 fileInputStream:104
resding  PNG : fileReader:8240 fileInputStream:137
```

i am using FileReader and FileInputStream for reading a txt file and reading an image file. i know on reads byte wise and other char wise. but im not getting this ouptput.

Comment: The PNG file probably contains an end-of-file character (ctrl-Z in Windows, ctrl-D in Linux/Unix) that causes the FileReader, which is designed for text, to conclude the input is done.

Comment: If you want to read image file you should use `Image image = ImageIO.read("File instance OR URL");`

Comment: no my aim is not to read the image file, but just wanted to clear the abOVE OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileReader:

> Convenience class for reading **character** files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.

FileInputStream:

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

Comment: my txt input file size is 1KB
PNG input file is 274 KB

Comment: That has precisely nothing to do with it. The point is that you shouldn't be using a Reader on a binary file at all, or indeed on any file that you don't know in advance to be text.

Answer (score 1):

The first byte in a PNG file is 0x89, or 137 decimal.  FileInputStream reports the byte as is, while FileReader assumes that it is a character in the Windows 1252 code page and converts it to the corresponding UTF-8 character code, 0x2030, or 8240 decimal.  (This assumes you ran the code on a Windows machine with default code page 1252).